# php form isn't mailing

Tags: php, javascript, forms, email

I have a div on a website that when clicked replaces the content of the current page with a form (the form is created with javascript, yes I know it's weird). It's a very simple form, a text input a textarea and a button type=submit. On submit, I have it call my php mail page (form.php). Nothing happens. Anyone know why?

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$to = "theemail@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Someone has contacted you from your website";
$message = $_POST['theMessage'];
$from = $_POST['theEmail'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header( 'Location: http://www.thesite.com/index.php' ) ;
?>
```

And here's my js:

```
var theForm = '\
<from action="../form.php" method="post"> \
    <div class="title blueTxt">Your Email Address:</div>\
    <input type="text" name="theEmail"> \
    <div class="title blueTxt">Your Message:</div>\
    <textarea name="theMessage"></textarea><br> \
    <button type="submit">Send</button>\
    \
</form>';

$('a .callToAction').on('click',function(){
    $('.content').html(theForm);
});
```

I have tried several things, but they haven't worked: changing the path for the form.php in the js; using input type=submit as opposed to button. These didn't work, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `form.php` is actually reached?  Check your access logs.  Are there any errors on form.php?

Comment: For one... your `form` tag says `<from>`... Change it to `<form ...`. Try that to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a spelling mistake to me:

from action...

Should be:

form action...

Comment: Easily done, earlier today I lost a whole hour because my code had == instead or != somewhere :)